# Adding a controllerview from Storyboard cancels the TapGesture assigned to UIImageViews in my view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, ios6, uistoryboard

So in a view, let's say "A", I have multiple UIImage views and UITextViews. Now, this is all done programatically. Within this same view, I am doing this:

```
if(!_productionLinesCollectionViewController)
{
    _productionLinesCollectionViewController = [[self storyboard]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductionLinesCollection"];
    _productionLinesCollectionViewController.productionLines = [_plant.productionLines allObjects];
    _productionLinesCollectionViewController.initX = 0;
    _productionLinesCollectionViewController.initY = _totalHeight;
    _productionLinesCollectionViewController.width = 668;
}

[self.scrollView addSubview:_productionLinesCollectionViewController.view];
```

Now for some reason, this is "cancelling" all the UITapGestures that I have assigned earlier (within the same view) (Also, this code is working in some other views 100%). Whenever I remove this piece of code, my gestures work again. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

```
UIImageView *playMovieImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"press_to_play.png"]];
playMovieImage.frame = CGRectMake(30, _totalHeight, 608, 456);
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(playMovie:)];
[playMovieImage addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
playMovieImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.scrollView addSubview:playMovieImage];
```

Comment: Is your imageview covering the whole UIView? Otherwise it should detect the previous gestures when you tap outside imageview.

Comment: It is not covering the whole... It is as if the new UIViewController from Storyboard prevents any gestures to be recognized.....